# How to input data into input fields whose names are changing after every visit in php?

Tags: php

I have been trying to input some data into following fields but since there are too many fields, most of them are hidden and only 2 are visible. So I'm wondering if there is any way in php so that I can input data into only visible input fields and then submit them using curl or anything.  Which would you suggest?  Then I want to run a loop to enter different data into the fields from a comma separated value file, text file or may be in a string?

The div name and input names are changing on every visit so can't even target with name or id etc..

Here is the form code which I am trying to target but since it's changing every time so how it can be done please :

```
<form action="" method="post">
<div class="uzuyjgec">
<input name="kAEuwLjmplRMZazfl/s9bW6YpnOxDDX2/2K0sobG" class="tbox" type="text">
</div>
<div class="tyqtmvha">
<input name="kwHKrLjmplTDzY/lMx57neltV9ErW378S1mX9h5S" class="tbox" type="text">
</div>
<input name="submit" value="Search!" class="tbox" type="submit">
</form>
```

I just took out the code for the inputs but it's so confusing.  There are too many inputs in the code...!

Here is full original code in live state : http://jsfiddle.net/rt1ff6ab/

It's showing as too many inputs in live state in jsfiddle but it's showing only 2 inputs in the site here it screenshot please as :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/451QH.png

Comment: Only two fields will be visible always. and other will be hidden. if yes then make two fields as input type="text" and make other as input type="hidden" then loop through input type= "text". It may help you.

Comment: it will be great if you can please post some code..really not getting in that way..! @ManojSharma

Comment: Did it occur that they might have set it up that way on purpose as to help prevent automated data entry?  Looks like you are dealing with a login form.  Exactly what are you trying achieve?

Comment: Not really it's a search form in a game site where I want to automate it so that I won't need to enter user names manually...!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just try this example. I hope it will help some where in your problem.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var ctr = 1;
                $('form input[type="text"]').each(function(){
                    ctr++;
                    $(this).val("Hello"+ctr);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" style=" border-bottom: 0px solid #3D4456;border-left: 0px solid #7885A7; border-right: 0px solid #3D4456;    border-top: 0px solid #6F7B9A;  ">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                    <td class="header" colspan="3"><div align="center" class="unnamed1">Search</div></td>
                    </tr>

                <input type="hidden" name="postsecret" class="tbox" value="ae12ee24d353a1ce0d0f1d2b4e6a9c2a">
                <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#000033"><font color="#999999">Username:</font></td>
                <td bgcolor="#000033"><div class="ppeahrsb"><input name="fQCOA43HplS/DtcTleFoEfPHCizE4LzJ4oOsG4fm" type="text" class="tbox"></div>
                <div class="dgodcaqx"><input name="gABI/43HplSxMbsniwA81un550YMF6cB3z3q2vb8" type="hidden" class="tbox"></div>
                <div class="acaramne"><input name="hACwfI3HplSRnmWaKbVT4V8aFFs2XGpg+N15SlRf" type="hidden" class="tbox">
                </div><div class="wdxcabya"><input name="hwDWBI3HplTB/9FW5XWsZibHLpXB9/Pegwqgxbtb" type="hidden" class="tbox"></div>
                <div class="dgodcaqx"><input name="igBZG43HplRHwYqQKxsvLtXuXHcO9KIa8jWECGT9" type="hidden" class="tbox"></div>
                <div class="ppeahrsb"><input name="jgAs5I3HplSomQBfoWfBRCKpXppHgFFjk//nLIF/" type="hidden" class="tbox"></div>
                <div class="acaramne"><input name="kQB//o3HplSZgWVqig2sBIuo92E0ga0D4OxE1Crg" type="hidden" class="tbox"></div></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#000033"><font color="#999999">Hours:</font></td>
                <td bgcolor="#000033"><div class="acaramne"><input name="lQBJyo3HplRt9Dd6P/A8ypTKWxuJyQaptYk/Zlnn" type="text" class="tbox"></div>
                <div class="ppeahrsb"><input name="mAAYtY3HplTmD5Fo/bkZyhLkdC02BhbEVrURmNqJ" type="hidden" class="tbox"></div>
                <div class="dgodcaqx"><input name="mwCxjY3HplRmf08annwDVJVGPhzAt/Vvj4F00Q98" type="hidden" class="tbox"></div>
                <div class="wdxcabya"><input name="nwBNT43HplTVt8dIeYA1AII+F84hD5+tAf6kjS83" type="hidden" class="tbox"></div>
                <div class="acaramne"><input name="ogCM9Y3HplS0beyr8v+Twl+TJWbP+PpNEtLzZgbQ" type="hidden" class="tbox"></div>
                <div class="dgodcaqx"><input name="pgB32I3HplQ6Jp5wnlOA4/Ndjqkt1AURhf4Yu1Et" type="hidden" class="tbox"></div>
                <div class="ppeahrsb"><input name="qQBjv43HplTr3qe2Kjuo8afgC9WWkrzU5fDpsW+Q" type="hidden" class="tbox"></div></td>
                </tr>

                <tr><td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Search!" class="tbox"></td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks..for your code...but really I want in php not in jQuery..!

Comment: you can retrieve that php value on ajax call as json and put that value in the field using same code.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to simulate a complete transaction. So

1. Use cUrl to load the form and enable cookies so you establish a session
2. Use Simple HTML DOM parser (or similar) to retrieve the field names
3. Use same cUrl session, post values for fields found in step 2